# Install org.json in pom.xml without karaf console

Tags: json, maven, apache-karaf

I need the org.json dependency in my servicemix project. This dependency does not exist yet so I need to import and install it.

So this is how I add my dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>
```

I could install it in karaf using:

```
install wrap:mvn:org.json/json/20170516
```

But I want to install it through my pom.xml or feature.xml so I don't have to install it every time I build my servicemix server.

Comment: you can install it by using 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20180130</version>
  </dependency>
Might the version you are using is not correct

Recent released https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20190722

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create you custom feature file. [ref](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_provisioning)

```
<features name="Features(JSON)">
    <feature name="org.json" version="20170516" description="JSON Library">
        <bundle start="true" start-level="80">mvn:org.json/json/20170516</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

and add it in karaf using command

```
feature:repo-add
```